# Precise word to describe this feeling

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

The word I'm looking for is probably a synonym of 'discouraged' or 'disheartened'.

**Context**: You are working on some project, and it has been going smooth so far. Suddenly a problem or challenge presents itself, and you feel that you are ill-equipped to deal with it or that it seems "too difficult". As a result you feel less than good, you lack confidence that you can do it, and you try to either procrastinate or side-step it.

**Example sentence**: In the above story, John felt ___.

What's the best word to describe this feeling?

'dishearten' as it is defined -- "to cause to lose hope, enthusiasm, or courage" -- is not a bad word, as in this context one does lose enthusiasm as well as confidence (courage?) in proceeding. But bear in mind that the word I'm looking for is in project-context (of a knowledge worker) rather than any dramatic life context.

Above all, it is a word to describe the feeling. To put a precise label on it.

## Clarifications

### Why not a generic word (like 'discouraged')?

"discouraged" is a fine *generic* word to describe this. My desire to be more precise however arises from motivation of [affect labeling](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Affect_labeling).

I think "discouraged" doesn't quite capture the faux inevitability of the situation. If I did not feel overwhelmed, I would not be discouraged. I would not be dispirited, but rather kept on feeling *spirited* when presented with an seemingly insurmountable challenge.

### Related concept in psychology

This word connotes a mindset that people tend to have, on easily giving up on a challenge (the word itself refers to the *feeling* engendered by it). Carol Dweck calls the *opposite* mindset as "growth mindset".

Comment: Hmm, could the downvoter/ flagger describe their rationale for burrying this question down? I did give a clear *context* to the question, which pretty much is a verbose alternative to any example you can give.

Comment: Okay, I've added a "sample sentence" per the rules (not that it clarifies the question any further but whatever).

Comment: For me, I'd lose momentum in the situation, *rudderless*. And note that challenging a downvote leaves our knowledge workers here disheartened, discouraged, and rudderless.

Comment: If there was a word that was a combination of "incapable" and "discouraged", would that be acceptable, or does the word need to inherently denote a worker/creator working on a project?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Point taken re: challenging a downvote, my apologies - and I'll try to be kind next time. (rudderless is an interesting word; never came across it!)

Comment: @TylerN I've added a clarification, hopefully that helps. Rather than "incapable" I'd say "a feeling of believing that one would be incapable of" (when factually that is not necessarily the case). That word should reflect the (affective) psychology of the situatoin more than the situation itself.

Comment: ["frustrated"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/frustrated) ?

Comment: In the example sentence, does "John" refer to the "you" in the context? It would be helpful to change "you" to "John" throughout (and maybe change the whole story to past tense) if that's what is meant. "John had been working on a project, and it was going smoothly... Suddenly a problem presented itself. [What kind of problem?] John felt ill-equipped to handle this new problem, and so he lost confidence and began to procrastinate. John felt ____." Notice that by casting this as a story, we are forced to omit all the weasel-words like "problem _or_ challenge," "procrastinate _or_ sidestep."

Comment: John might feel **stymied** or **baffled** by the new problem, causing him to **lose momentum**... but those words might not address the desired "feeling" part.

Comment: What's wrong with "overwhelmed"? You've actually used it in your question...

Comment: This kind of question can be answered by browsing available words in a [thesaurus](https://thesaurus.com/browse/discourage).

Comment: [woebegone](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/woebegone), maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In effect, John felt **deflated**.

As the [Cambridge dictionary defines it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deflated):

> feeling less confident and positive than before:
>
> > Her criticism left me feeling a bit deflated

The metaphor is of something inflatable, e.g., a ball, and earlier on, when things were going well in the project, the ball was full of air (positive emotions and energy in working on the project), but when the overwhelming challenge came, it deflated the ball.

Another good word might be [crestfallen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crestfallen):

> disappointed and sad because of having failed unexpectedly:
>
> > He looked crestfallen at their decision

Comment: I like these words, because they also imply that the new emotion state is the result of transitioning from the opposite emotion. Another word is: feeling **spirited**, until a *seemingly* insurmountable challenge presents itself, triggering one into feeling **dispirited** instead.

Comment: Thanks @SridharRatnakumar , yes, spirited/dispirited would convey a similar idea.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish conveying this idea, one could structure the sentence in a way to describe the challenge rather than the person who has been presented with the challenge.

> Suddenly a seemingly **insurmountable** problem or challenge presented itself.

But, to address your question more directly

> the word I'm looking for is in project-context (of a knowledge worker) rather than any dramatic life context. Above all, it is a word to describe the feeling.

I'm not sure why **discouraged** isn't acceptable, I belive it is a word that fits quite nicely.

> Discouraged, adjective
>
> > [If you work on a project [...] you may feel discouraged, meaning *your enthusiasm and optimism have been replaced by doubt and negativity*.](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/discouraged)

Otherwise, you're just looking at other synonyms of discouraged; all of which mean something along the lines of: daunted, devitalized, to lose hope, to not feel good enough, to want to avoid something due to feeling inadequate.

To my knowledge there is no single word that is specific to working on a project, but **discouraged** or any of its synonyms are very commonly used when referring to a project, and usually the context is enough to supply that information.

### Possibly Related

The Dunning-Kruger Effect, wherein one who knows little about something thinks they are above average, and someone who has learned, knows a good bit, and has experience about something initially feels stupid on the subject (usually due to feeling overwhelmed) before beginning to gain confidence again.

[image]

Comment: "discouraged" is a fine *generic* word to describe this. My desire to be more precise however arises from motivation of [affect labeling](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Affect_labeling).

I think "discouraged" doesn't quite capture the faux inevitability of the situation. If I did not feel overwhelmed, I would not be discouraged. I would not be dispirited, but rather kept on feeling *spirited* when presented with an seemingly insurmountable (nice word, btw) challenge.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar So if this word did exist, the definition would more or less be, "to feel discouraged and/or incapable due to feeling overwhelmed by a challenge"?

Comment: More or less, yes. Put differently, the feeling of being *discouraged/ dispirited/ deflated* etc is **triggered** by a specific belief of seeing oneself incapable of surmounting a challenge (one gets overwhelmed by it, instead of seeing it as an enjoyable challenge to overcome with *continued spiritedness*)

Comment: A very related psychological concept is Carol Dweck's "Growth Mindset".

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar Unfortunately in this situation it might be best to just be wordy and explain what you've been explaining on here in your writing/speech, as there doesn't seem to be a perfect single-word. I also edited my post with a semi-related effect you might be interested in.